# Copy & paste a range into selected range in Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z9cVj.png)Can't find a solution for my task.
In google spreedsheets Copy range Constant Range E30:Q30 and paste into current cell but in selected array for example
E33:Q132 (any string, E44:Q44 or E42:Q42 etc)
So if I select different array to paste for ex. E12:Q12 it will show msg box "Try another cell"
I understand that it is simple but I`m new in JS
Thank you for your help

Added script

```
function CopyPaste2() { 
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive(); 
  //spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 1, 13).activate(); 
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Copy of StopWatch'), true); 
  spreadsheet.getRange('Copy of StopWatch!E30:Q30').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false); 
};
```

Comment: Sorry, don't understand your question.  Could you provide more detail.  Visual example would help.

Comment: @TheWizEd add picture 
I need copy and paste range E30:Q30 (yellow) to defined range E33:Q50 (blue) but in one row what i wil choose 
However if I select a row outside the defined range to show a message box with text "Select another cell"

Comment: I want to avoid mistakes paste range E30:Q30 not in correct row

Comment: Is it that you want to always copy E30:Q30 to the next empty row in the range E33:Q?  And if you try to copy some other range to E33:Q, show an error message?  And is it simple copy and paste or through a button or menu item?

Comment: @TheWizEd
Is it that you want to always copy E30:Q30 to the next empty row in the range E33:Q?
 - yes, always copy E30:Q30 (numbers will be changing). Not to the next empty row but I need to be able select row where to paste 

And if you try to copy some other range to E33:Q, show an error message? 
- Yes, correct

And is it simple copy and paste or through a button or menu item?
-  through a button.

Comment: Now I have this gs process

function CopyPaste2() {
  var spreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //spreadsheet.getCurrentCell().offset(0, 0, 1, 13).activate();
  spreadsheet.setActiveSheet(spreadsheet.getSheetByName('Copy of StopWatch'), true);
  spreadsheet.getRange('Copy of StopWatch!E30:Q30').copyTo(spreadsheet.getActiveRange(), SpreadsheetApp.CopyPasteType.PASTE_VALUES, false);
};

Comment: Rather than select a range, why not just pick a row E33:Q?  Any cell within that range?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how I would copy values from E30:Q30 to any row E33:Q.  Since your script uses PASTE_VALUES there is no need to use copy but simply setValues().

And I assume you are copying to the same sheet.

```
function runTest() {
  let cell = SpreadsheetApp.getCurrentCell();  // any cell in the range E33:Q
  let sheet = cell.getSheet();
  if( sheet.getName() === "Sheet1" ) {
    if( cell.getRow() > 32 ) {  // row 33 and up
      if( ( cell.getColumn() > 4 ) && ( cell.getColumn() < 18 ) ) {  // columns E to Q
        let values = sheet.getRange("E30:Q30").getValues();
        sheet.getRange(cell.getRow(),5,1,13).setValues(values);
        return;
      }
    }
    SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert("Try another cell");
  }
}
```